# How to create a filter on AWS CoudWatch to detect non JSON Log events?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, filter, amazon-cloudwatch

I need to filter logs which are not JSON. let's say the only thing we know about the log is that it's either a JSON log with a message in it or a plain text log which could be anything. How to write a filter pattern to spot only the plain ones?
something like the below doesn't work on plain ones (it is applied only on structured logs)
`{$.message NOT EXISTS}`
I need something like below:
`{logs which are NOT JSONS}`

Answer (score 0):

As per the AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html#matching-terms-events), you can use the NOT EXISTS operator only within curly braces. This means that the mentioned filter only works within a JSON object, so you cannot use `{ $.* NOT EXISTS }` to filter non-JSON messages.

As a result, you are left with the regex filter alone to fetch non-JSON messages. Even with the regex filter, you cannot use the NOT operator, so making it difficult to fetch messages without curly braces. Hence, there is no direct way to filter non-JSON messages from CloudWatch.

However, if you know the patterns of all your non-JSON messages, you can create a regex pattern such a way to filter those messages from CloudWatch.